# How to walk along a Java shape and translate it to left/right/straight commands?

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d, vector-graphics

I have Java Shape objects. If I follow the line for example pixel by pixel it would translate to a sequence of straight, straight, ... commands. If I follow a circle, I would be something like left, straight, left, straight, ... How can I solve this with Java?

Answer (score 2):

I would get a pathIterator from the shape,

```
public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform at)
```

and from the iterator, call

```
int currentSegment(double[] coords)
```

then given the starting and ending pt, you can calculate the slope of the line.

At any segment along the way, if you have the slop of the previous line seqment, and the slope of the current line segment, you can tell in what relative direction to go using the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to determine the angle.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably pick a starting pixel, store it in an array and then look for surrounding pixels not in that array, store the direction it took to get there, and so on.

Comment: Well, I hope there is a better way :)

Comment: Perhaps, but it wouldn't be as much fun! :)